# How to get a child sprite position in the view

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, skspritenode, sknode

I am attempting to get the child sprites position in the view based on the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15883305/using-convertpoint-to-get-the-relative-position-inside-a-parent-uiview) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21865357/ios-spritekit-child-nodes-position-with-respect-to-view-coordinates)

```
for child in platformGroupNode.children {
    CGPoint p = [child.superview convertPoint:child.center toNode:self.view ]
    println(p)
}
```

However I am unsure how to use this with `SKSpriteNode` Children and `SKNode` Parents.

I have also tried this with no luck

```
for child in platformGroupNode.children {
    var pos = child.position
    var viewPos = convertPoint(pos, toNode: self.parent!)
    if viewPos.x < 0 {
        println("Out of screen")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're nearly there, what you need to use is:

```
let positionInScene = self.convertPoint(child.position, fromNode: platformGroupNode)
// self in this case is your SKScene, you don't need self here but, IMO, it 
// makes it easier to understand what's converting what.
```

Or an equivalent would be:

```
let positionInScene = platformGroupNode.convertPoint(child.position, toNode: self)
```